Problem with software updates
I have this error message when I run the Software Updater on Ubuntu 24.10:
Unable to recover http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oracular/InRelease  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 193.206.214.15 80]

I have no idea what's going on! Could you help me please?

You're currently using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.mirror.garr.it which maybe has temporary problems; you could always switch to using a different mirror (or the main archive).   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors shows a list of mirrors (main mirror will be used if you just drop the 'it.' at the start of your current link(s))

This is the message after I've changed mirror: "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.". It is connected to internet, that is not the problem.
